# Sort the list of string in which some string begin with parentheses in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to order a list of string where some begin with parenthesis. I want to order in ascending way, but the string with the parenthesis should be at the end.

```
const items = 
      ['ABC - Desk 1 ', 
       'NDF - Desk 2 ' ,
       '(Busy) DEF - desk 3 ',
       '(Busy) Test desk ']
```

I trying with:

```
if(orderAsc){
    items.sort((item1, item2) =>  item1.localeCompare(item2));
} else {
   items.sort((item1, item2) => item2.localeCompare(item1));
}
```

but the result is

```
> "(Busy) DEF - desk 3 "
> "(Busy) Test desk "
> "ABC - Desk 1 "
> "NDF - Desk 2 "
```

else

```
> "NDF - Desk 2 "
> "ABC - Desk 1 "
> "(Busy) Test desk "
> "(Busy) DEF - desk 3 "
```

What I need is

```
'ABC - Desk 1 ', 
'NDF - Desk 2 ' ,
'(Busy) DEF - desk 3 ',
'(Busy) Test desk '
```

Where without parentheses are the firsts and after those with the parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this function and it produces the exact output you're looking for.

```js
const items = ['ABC - Desk 1 ',
    'NDF - Desk 2 ',
    '(Busy) DEF - desk 3 ',
    '(Busy) Test desk '
]

const sortedItems = items.sort((a, b) => {
    const aBusy = a.includes('(Busy)');
    const bBusy = b.includes('(Busy)');
    if (aBusy && !bBusy) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (!aBusy && bBusy) {
        return -1;
    }
    return a.localeCompare(b);
});

console.log(sortedItems)
```

Comment: Actually even just with  
´const aBusy = a.includes('(');´
    ´const bBusy = b.includes('(');´
works fine !

Answer (score 0):

You could do a temporary replacement character or string to ensure that the items go last in the array.

```js
const items = ['(Busy) DEF - desk 3 ', 'NDF - Desk 2 ', '(Busy) Test desk ', 'ABC - Desk 1 ']
let sorted = items.map(m => m.replace("(", "ZZZ|")).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)).map(m => m.replace("ZZZ|", "("))
console.log(sorted)
```